# Python 3.7/buildozer - Application crash on Android after start

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I want to compile my python script to APK and run it on Android. I'm using kivy, os, pika, threading, and own module "RabbitMQ".
Lubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.6
and for code I use Python 3.7. 
In buildozer.spec I've got `requirements = python3,kivy,RabbitMQ` and `android.permissions = INTERNET`.

When I run my app on Android it starts loading and then it just crash.

Here are my logcat logs:

```
01-18 21:28:27.937 29220 29255 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
01-18 21:28:27.937 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
01-18 21:28:27.937 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/jnius/__init__.py", line 54, in jnius_thread_hook
01-18 21:28:27.938 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3-libffi-openssl-sqlite3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/threading.py", line 865, in run
01-18 21:28:27.938 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 216, in start
01-18 21:28:27.938 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
01-18 21:28:27.938 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 211, in build
01-18 21:28:27.939 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 96, in __init__
01-18 21:28:27.939 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
01-18 21:28:27.939 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
01-18 21:28:27.940 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 361, in __init__
01-18 21:28:27.940 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
01-18 21:28:27.940 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
01-18 21:28:27.941 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 659, in _apply_rule
01-18 21:28:27.941 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 654, in _apply_rule
01-18 21:28:27.941 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 188, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__cinit__
01-18 21:28:27.941 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 447, in kivy.properties.Property.link
01-18 21:28:27.942 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 632, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.init_storage
01-18 21:28:27.942 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 418, in kivy.properties.Property.init_storage
01-18 21:28:27.942 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 655, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.convert
01-18 21:28:27.942 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 663, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_str
01-18 21:28:27.943 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 670, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_list
01-18 21:28:27.943 29220 29255 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 296, in kivy.properties.dpi2px
01-18 21:28:27.943 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/utils.py", line 505, in __get__
01-18 21:28:27.943 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/metrics.py", line 163, in dpi
01-18 21:28:27.944 29220 29255 I python  :    File "/home/virtual/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/jnius/reflect.py", line 159, in autoclass
01-18 21:28:27.944 29220 29255 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_func.pxi", line 26, in jnius.jnius.find_javaclass
01-18 21:28:27.944 29220 29255 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: Class not found b'org/renpy/android/Hardware'
01-18 21:28:27.944 29220 29255 I python  :
```

Comment: This error is surprising, it's indicating that a certain java class can't be found but this java class should be present, I don't see why this small thing should randomly fail.

Comment: If you do a trivial build that just runs kivy and has no extra requirements, does that work?

Comment: Yes. When I build simple Hello World it works fine

Comment: Interesting, I really don't know why this would be. Does it fail the same way if you redo the build from scratch?

Comment: I deleted all buildozer files, rebuild and I still get this error.

Comment: Also, I'm using threading, and before error I get `Exception in thread Thread-4`. App somehow works, because it reads message from RabbitMQ server.

Answer (score 0):

There's 'jnius' in the errors, are you using it in your app? If so, just add 'pyjnius' to requirements in the spec file.

Comment: No, I'm not using it.